# MySql Community Server Minimum System Requirements

Tags: mysql, windows, system-requirements

Can anyone point me to a link or provide me information about the minimum System/Hardware requirements required to run/install MySql Community Server on a windows machine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installation.html), you'll see that there are no hardware requirements defined.

If you think about it, this is pretty logical since the required hardware will greatly depend on your schema and data.

If you look at the answer below you'll find a calculator for needed memory that could be a start to define how much RAM you need.

I would say any computer beefy enough to run windows will also be able to run MySQL without much issues. Then, you might have to update your hardware based on your database.

Sorry for not being able to give a better answer ;)

Comment: I don't see any word about how much minimum RAM/Memory is required. Do you have any suggestions for the minimum memory requirements.
I got a 128MB RAM computer and its pretty old. Though it may sound stone age, but yes I was tasked to install MySQL on that windows machine. 
Thanks,

Comment: @Adi The need in RAM depends on the database schema, quantity of data, number of connection, etc. There's no real lower or upper limit.

Comment: I've install mySQL Community Edition on a Raspberry Pi without issue.

Comment: Surely there has to be a lower limit.

Comment: No sir as far as the question goes, nothing is in the manual.

Comment: Thanks @TuncayGöncüoğlu, your comment makes me see that my answer was not clear enough thus I updated it. Hope it's better now :)

Comment: This is an old post but I've been trying to install MySQL 8 on fresh Ubuntu 20.04 instances with 512mb of RAM.
It will crash 100% of the time with `Out of memory: Killed process`. 
It should be possible to use swapfile to circumvent this problem.

Answer (score 15):

Oracle doesn't seem to publish any minimum hardware requirements because the minimum will depend largely on how each user uses the database. A nice tool I found for calculating your specific minimum requirements is [MySQL Calculator](http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/).

According to MySQL Calculator, based on MySQL's defaults, you will need 576.2 MB of RAM for the program. **By adjusting the settings to the absolute minimums, I got a value of just under 8MB.** Of course, such low settings will render MySQL very slow and limited but at least that gives you a theoretical starting point.

Comment: and what are those minimum settings, anyone with an example config?